# python3: set and itertools.groupby yielding different outcomes?

Tags: python, python-itertools, whois

I have some Apache access logs I want to parse using `IPWhois`.

I want to group the `IPWhois` results based on the `asn_description` field.

Isn't the fact that the `set` and the `itertools.groupby()` in the following snippet yeild different outcomes?

```py
descs = set()

with open(RESULTSFILE, 'a+') as r:
    for description, items in groupby(results, key=lambda x: x['asn_description']):
        print('ASN Description: ' + description)
        descs.add(description)

print(descs)
```

e.g.

```
ASN Description: GOOGLE - Google LLC, US
ASN Description: AVAST-AS-DC, CZ
ASN Description: FACEBOOK - Facebook, Inc., US
ASN Description: AVAST-AS-DC, CZ
ASN Description: AMAZON-AES - Amazon.com, Inc., US
ASN Description: FACEBOOK - Facebook, Inc., US
ASN Description: AMAZON-02 - Amazon.com, Inc., US
ASN Description: AMAZON-02 - Amazon.com, Inc., US
ASN Description: GOOGLE - Google LLC, US
ASN Description: GOOGLE-2 - Google LLC, US
ASN Description: AMAZON-02 - Amazon.com, Inc., US
{'FACEBOOK - Facebook, Inc., US', 'AVAST-AS-DC, CZ', 'AMAZON-AES - Amazon.com, Inc., US', 'GOOGLE-2 - Google LLC, US', 'GOOGLE - Google LLC, US', 'AMAZON-02 - Amazon.com, Inc., US',
```

Comment: Set will return unique values over all, groupby only returns consecutive unique values

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following and try. If you donot need `items` perhaps drop it from the for loop by using a `_` in its place.

```py
import itertools
descs = dict()

with open(RESULTSFILE, 'a+') as r:
    for i, (description, items) in enumerate(itertools.groupby(results, key=lambda x: x['asn_description'])):
        print('ASN Description: ' + description)
        descs.update({i: description})

print(descs)
```